# Splitscreen multiseat? (one screen, multiple users)

Tags: multiseat

There are many online guides regarding multiseat with multiple screens and multicursor with a shared workspace in Ubuntu/Mint/etc., but I would also like to be able to split a single screen into two halves, so that two users can work seperately, independently from each other and without interference or needing an external screen.

Of course, the screen size for each user is only half (duh!), but that's fine during the multiseat usage.

On an 17.3" laptop, even four users on one HD+ 1600×900p screen could work for sinple tasks such as E-Mails, documents and data management, due to sufficient screen size and processing performance.

#### What are ways to have multiseat within one screen?

Comment: Classic multiseat is based on multiple XServers, which have their dedicated screen (or tty), keyboard, mouse, etc. Running multiple XServers is out of the question in your scenario. That means that you would have to show more independent cursors on one screen (with one XServer) controled each by a dedicated mouse. That, in my opinion, would require quite significant changes in X software. I have serious doubts you would be able to do it only with configuration tweaks.

Comment: @Nobody But then the users would interfere with each other

Comment: @Nobody +1, but I expect **LINUX,** which is considered as technically leading OS,  to be able to do that. Cam FreeBSD do so?

Comment: Yes, users would interfere with each other, because they would all use the same screen. There is physically not enough room for more users at one screen. Each mouse cursor should be trapped in the portion of screen where desktop of that user is. In that way, cursors would not interfere. Mouse and keyboard would work only in the dedicated part of the screen. However, as I said, I don't believe it can be done without some serious programming.

Comment: @Nobody Is there not already one existing tool?

Comment: One solution that comes to my mind is to install virtual machines. I think you can dedicate USB ports (mouse & keyboard) to a virtual machine. In that way, you can have more virtual machines on one screen and each can have its own mouse and keyboard. You can also trap a mouse within virtual machine.